# How to synchronize two text areas within separate iframes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two iframes, both of which contain a form with a text area.

My goal is to synchronize the two text areas, so that what the user types in one is reproduced in the other. How can I do this across two (or more) separate iframes?

Main document:

```
<script>
$("iframe").ready(function(){
    $(".editor").keyup(function(){
        $(".editor").val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>

<iframe src="/editor.php?mode=post&f=1" class="iframe-editor"></iframe>
<iframe src="/editor.php?mode=post&f=2" class="iframe-editor"></iframe>
```

Content of the iframes:

```
<fieldset class="fields1">

    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="editor">{MESSAGE}</textarea>

</fieldset>
```

As of now, my jquery script only works if the text areas are placed in the main document.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can't have javascript that affects an inner (or outer) iframe for security reasons.

Comment: I think that's true if the iframe belongs to a different domain. In my case, both the main document and the iframes are in the same domain.

Comment: not sure it can be done if I'm wrong (I hope^^) tell since I'm interested too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up doesn't work because ".editor" belongs to another DOM. However, you can access that DOM by using the ["contentWindow" property of the IFRAME element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow).

You can also pass `myIframe.contentWindow.document` as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) to jquery, so that jquery searches there.

http://jsfiddle.net/cbv0xfq2/

```
$('.iframe-editor').each(function() {
  var frame = this;

  $(frame.contentWindow.document.body).on('input', '.editor', function() {
    var textarea = $(this);
    $(".iframe-editor").not(frame).each(function() {
      $('.editor', this.contentWindow.document).val(textarea.val());
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it doesn't seem to be working on my end. Is it supposed to have `.iframe-editor` in the 1st line and `.containerFrame` in the 6th?